# Django: Group By between two range of Dates that are not present in Database

Tags: python, mysql, django, date, group-by

I am currently making an API in Django Rest Framework and in that I am filtering the dates which was given by the user(coming from frontend) and after then I am grouping it in months. The problem I am facing is what if the start date is lesser than min(createddate), then the data I am getting is filtered but instead of that I need the grouped time from start date to the end date(grouped in a range), if there is no data for some months then the database should return 0.

I know SQL(I am using SQL as my DB) evaluates first where clause and after group by, is there a way to group the data first and then we could apply where clause.

For example:

`Body` -  I am passing to the API

```
{
    "StartDate":"2017-06-01",
    "EndDate":"2017-08-08"
}
```

`Current Response` - I am getting from my API

```
"data": [
    {
        "key": "Count",
        "bar": true,
        "values": [
            [
                "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
                1501545600000,
                1
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

`Correct Response` - I wanted from data

```
"data": [
        {
            "key": "Count",
            "bar": true,
            "values": [
                [
                    "2017-06-01T00:00:00",
                    1496255400000,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    "2017-07-01T00:00:00",
                    1498847400000,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
                    1501545600000,
                    1
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Django ORM query:

```
q=ConsumerServicerequestFeedback.objects.values_list('csrfrating').filter(status)

    if len(StartDate) != 0 and len(EndDate) == 0:
        StartDate = datetime.strptime(StartDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
        next_day = StartDate + timedelta(1)
        q = q.filter(csrfcreateddate__range=[StartDate, next_day])
    elif len(StartDate) != 0 and len(EndDate) != 0:
        q = q.filter(csrfcreateddate__range=[StartDate, EndDate])
    elif len(StartDate) == 0 and len(EndDate) != 0:
        EndDate = datetime.strptime(EndDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
        q = q.filter(csrfcreateddate__lte=EndDate)

q.annotate(Time=TruncMonth('csrfcreateddate')).values('Time').annotate(Count=Count('csrfrating')).values('Time', 'Count')
```

Comment: Post your django orm query here.

Comment: @AnupYadav posted.

Comment: To get better control over query and conditions to add, I would suggest write raw query to achieve this easily.

Comment: @AnupYadav Raw queries are generally avoided and using the raw queries won't be a good idea, until or unless I am out of options.

Comment: Nope, if you are using API and not processing anything in loops there is no issues, as you are already not using any lazy load, everything is eager loading, so better write down raw query, get the output and then you can define strategy to convert into Django ORM and then remove raw if possible.

Comment: Try using CASE or IF ELSE

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to make first annotate and then filter it.

You write

`q.annotate(
    Time=TruncMonth('csrfcreateddate')
).values('Time')
.annotate(
    Count=Count('csrfrating')
).values('Time', 'Count')`

this line before your `if elif` block Django make first annotate then filter it.
you can look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations) also

Comment: I guess it won't work as Django evaluates the queries lazily and in SQL the priority of where is more than group by.

Comment: Also, there is one more problem as the data is not present even after grouping, filtering won't work like the way I want.

What I wanted to do is group it between startdate and enddate and after put the count in between the months